Separate column value by space and dash
I'm using SQL in MS Access. I have a column in a table that has two types of codes in a single field that follow 4 different types of standards:
     MyColumn
XC120192 - XS38791
XC120192- XS38791
XC120192 -XS38791
XC120192 XS38791

I created two new columns called XC and XS to separate the codes and store them in their respective columns. The expected result would be something like this:
  XC      XS
XC120192  XS38791
XC120192  XS38791
XC120192  XS38791
XC120192  XS38791

How can I do this separation in a way that respects these four different types of separation standards?

This question is similar to: Splitting a Single Database Field into Multiple Fields. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If they are all the same length, left() and right() of that length

As you have fixed length codes:
Select 
    Left(MyColumn, 8) As XC, 
    Right(MyColumn, 7) As XS
From 
    YourTable

